# Reading NSWindow resize event

Tags: cocoa, event-handling, resize, nswindow

I was wondering if anyone knows, how do I read when NSWindow is being resized?
Let's imagine I have a button in an empty window (other than the button), then user resizes the window from the bottom right corner, now I should make it so that the button also resizes when the window is being resized. I know how to resize button, and I know how to resize a window, and I know lots of stuff, but I don't know how to get notificated when ever the user resizes the window, any tips?

Comment: Also, example is always the best answer, and giving a great example will totally make your answer the correct one, I guess it has something to do with NSWindowDelegate but not sure how to use it... :S

Comment: Did you figure out how to parse the notification to get width and height?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you use the [`‑windowDidResize:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419567-windowdidresize) delegate method?

Answer (score 5):

### in the awake from nib of your .m file write

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenResize) name:NSWindowDidResizeNotification object:nil];
```

## and create a method now

```
(void)screenResize
{
    NSRect rect = Preloader.frame;
    rect = NSMakeRect(self.view.frame.origin.x+self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.origin.y+self.view.frame.size.height/2, Preloader.frame.size.width, Preloader.frame.size.height);
    Preloader.frame = rect;
    NSLog(@"X = %f, Y = %f, W = %f, H= %f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
}
```

### and when you get out of that class write

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSWindowDidResizeNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score -2):

On Xcode 4.3 and later, use the [autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to add constraints to the button, you can get very complex layouts without writing any line of code  .

Comment: this isn't very helpful, and not to the point either. Sorry for downvote, but you should change your answer

Comment: I disagree; autolayout is is correct approach to resolving this issue.

Comment: they were asking about a resizing event, which is best handled in code. and in my opinion Apple still has a long way to go with their interface builder...